# Change root user password via terminal

Tags: mysql

I am trying to change the root user's password via the terminal because I am denied access.

The command I am running is:

```
UPDATE user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("newpass") where user='root';
```

But I get the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '("newpass") where user='root'' at line 1

I am trying to follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GeVMDQsDpc) (ca 2:20) and it seems to work fine there.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: I am working in macOS Mojave.

Comment: Instead of random videos, consult [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)!

Comment: Is table name `user` and column `user` are same ?

Comment: Also this very question was asked and solved in the third comment under the video.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you are right. but in the doc you sent, when i use the `ALTER` command i get: "ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement"

Comment: @Disasterkid Which section are you following? If the last one, did you use the `FLUSH` statement in step 2?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the `FLUSH` part goes well. Folder `ALTER USER` statement I get "Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)". I am in mac OS by the way.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am looking at the section **B.5.3.2.3 Resetting the Root Password: Generic Instructions**.

Comment: @Disasterkid It looks like your problem is related to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79027. Check the comments about `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` and/or using a normal `UPDATE` query.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following link which will give you the detailed procedure to change root password https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/

Comment: To qualify as an answer, you should include more than a link to instructions. As you can see there is already a comment with a link to the docs.

Comment: I probably forgot to say I run under macOS.